# instantaneous rate of growth

Tags: change-of-variable

> Populations of two species $A$ and $B$ at time $0$ are equal. If the
>   instantaneous rates of growth of populations of species $A$ and $B$
>   are $u$ and $u + 1$ respectively, $u > 0$, then at time $1$ the
>   population of species $B$ would be
>
> (a) twice the population of species $A$
>
> (b) $log 10$ times of the population of species $A$
>
> (c) $e^{u}$ times the population of species $A$
>
> (d) $e$ times the population of species $A$

I tries to understand instantaneous growth on the inernet but i found it very confusing, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

**Population at time t** : $N_o e^{\lambda t}$ where $N_o$ is the initial population and $\lambda$ is the rate of growth.

Thus the answer should be $e$ times the population of $A$

This was derived by:

$$\frac{dP}{dt}=k P$$
$$\int\frac{dP}{P}=\int k dt$$
$$\ln P=k t$$

Note, that population growth is proportional to current population